# iOS 10 - Objective-C : How to implement AVCapturePhotoOutput() to capture image and videos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, avcapturesession

I'm trying to implement capture image and videos from my app, and now from iOS 10 onward **"AVCaptureStillImageOutput"** is deprecated.

Please help me to implement **AVCapturePhotoOutput** in Objective-C.

Here is my sample code:

```
_avCaptureOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc]init];
_avSettings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettings];


AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[captureSession startRunning];



AVCaptureConnection *connection = [self.movieOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if (connection.active)
{
    //connection is active
    NSLog(@"Connection is active");

    id previewPixelType = _avSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.firstObject;
    NSDictionary *format = @{(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:previewPixelType,(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey:@160,(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey:@160};

    _avSettings.previewPhotoFormat = format;

    [_avCaptureOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:_avSettings delegate:self];


}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection is not active");
    //connection is not active
    //try to change self.captureSession.sessionPreset,
    //or change videoDevice.activeFormat
}
```

Comment: what is purpose of AVCapturePhotoOutput ?

Comment: did you implemented the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`?

Comment: what type is `self.movieOutput`?

Comment: self.movieOutput is kind of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput class. and yes i did implemented the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
_avCaptureOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc]init];
_avSettings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettings];

AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[captureSession startRunning];

[self.avCaptureOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:self.avSettings delegate:self];
```

self must implement the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate

```
#pragma mark - AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)photoSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)previewPhotoSampleBuffer resolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings bracketSettings:(AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings *)bracketSettings error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

    if (photoSampleBuffer) {
        NSData *data = [AVCapturePhotoOutput JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:photoSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
}
```

Now, you get the image, and do whatever you want.

---

**Note**: Since iOS 11, `-captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:...` is deprecated, need to use `-captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:` instead:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output didFinishProcessingPhoto:(AVCapturePhoto *)photo error:(nullable NSError *)error
{  
  NSData *imageData = [photo fileDataRepresentation];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Really easy implementation

Comment: How do you get the preview photo from this?